# CPU usage monitoring in the last bolt in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I tried to monitor the CPU usage of workers in Apache storm.  The CPU usage in the last worker, which receives all the messages, is significantly higher than the CPU usage in other workers. The number of messages processed in both workers, and the tasks in all the workers are the same. Does anybody know why this happens? I expected that for the workers with the same number of messages and the same task, the CPU usage will be the same.

More details:
I used the CPU metric of apache storm.
Each bolt is placed on a specific device.
For each bolt, we have one supervisor and one worker.

Update: I found the reason. The spouts always have a lower CPU usaage rather than the bolts.

Comment: What CPU metric exactly you use? Are these machines similar? It could be interesting to measure CPU usage separately. And: Basically, I would say that the usage depends as well on your implemented functionality, so if the components differ, the usage will differ of course.

Comment: @moosehead42 thank you for your comment. I updated the question. I used the Metric V2 for the CPU monitoring.